# How do I target an array inside an object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, target

I've got an array that returns more arrays and other data within objects. How do I target the data that is inside these objects? Is the name in front of an object in a var_export the actual name to which you can reference?

In the following example code:
I thought var_dump($product->WC_Product_Variation['variation_id']); would return "278" in stead it gives a NULL. What am I doing wrong in regards to targeting content inside an object?

Here is my var_export of $product:

```
array (
'product_id' => 259,
 'variation_id' => 278,
 'variation' =>
 array (
 'pa_afmetingen-liggend' => 'm011',
 ),
 'quantity' => 1,
 'data' =>
 WC_Product_Variation::__set_state(array(
 'variation_id' => 278,
 'parent' =>
 WC_Product_Variable::__set_state(array(
 'children' => NULL,
 'total_stock' => NULL,
 'id' => 259,
 'post' =>
 WP_Post::__set_state(array(
 'ID' => 259,
 'post_author' => '1',
 'post_date' => '2013-06-05 13:22:26',
 'post_date_gmt' => '2013-06-05 13:22:26',  'post_content' => 'liggend',  'post_title' => 'Wit liggend',  'post_excerpt' => '',  'post_status' => 'publish',  'comment_status' => 'open',  'ping_status' => 'closed',  'post_password' => '',  'post_name' => 'wit-liggend',  'to_ping' => '',  'pinged' => '',  'post_modified' => '2013-06-27 09:24:08',  'post_modified_gmt' => '2013-06-27 09:24:08',  'post_content_filtered' => '',  'post_parent' => 0,  'guid' => 'http://www.***.nl/?post_type=productp=259',
 'menu_order' => 0,
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'post_mime_type' => '',
 'comment_count' => '0',
 'filter' => 'raw',
 )),
 'product_type' => 'variable',
 )),
 'variation_data' =>
 array (
 'attribute_pa_afmetingen-liggend' => 'm011',  ),  'variation_has_length' => false,  'variation_has_width' => false,  'variation_has_height' => false,  'variation_has_weight' => false,  'variation_has_stock' => false,  'variation_has_sku' => false,  'variation_shipping_class' => false,  'variation_shipping_class_id' => false,  'variation_has_tax_class' => true,  'id' => 259,  'post' =>  WP_Post::__set_state(array(  'ID' => 259,  'post_author' => '1',  'post_date' => '2013-06-05 13:22:26',  'post_date_gmt' => '2013-06-05 13:22:26',  'post_content' => 'liggend',  'post_title' => 'Wit liggend',  'post_excerpt' => '',  'post_status' => 'publish',  'comment_status' => 'open',  'ping_status' => 'closed',  'post_password' => '',  'post_name' => 'wit-liggend',  'to_ping' => '',  'pinged' => '',  'post_modified' => '2013-06-27 09:24:08',  'post_modified_gmt' => '2013-06-27 09:24:08',  'post_content_filtered' => '',  'post_parent' => 0,  'guid' => 'http://www.***.nl/?post_type=productp=259',
 'menu_order' => 0,
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'post_mime_type' => '',
 'comment_count' => '0',
 'filter' => 'raw',
 )),
 'product_type' => 'variation',
 'product_custom_fields' =>
 array (
 '_sku' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_weight' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_length' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_width' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_height' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_stock' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_thumbnail_id' =>
 array (
 0 => '0',
 ),
 '_virtual' =>
 array (
 0 => 'no',
 ),
 '_downloadable' =>
 array (
 0 => 'no',
 ),
 '_regular_price' =>
 array (
 0 => '83',
 ),
 '_sale_price' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_sale_price_dates_from' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_sale_price_dates_to' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_price' =>
 array (
 0 => '83',
 ),
 '_tax_class' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_download_limit' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_download_expiry' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 '_file_paths' =>
 array (
 0 => '',
 ),
 'attribute_pa_afmetingen-liggend' =>
 array (
 0 => 'm011',
 ),
 ),
 'downloadable' => 'no',
 'virtual' => 'no',
 'tax_class' => '',
 'sale_price_dates_from' => '',
 'price' => '83',
 'regular_price' => '83',
 'sale_price' => '',
 'total_stock' => 0,
 )),
 'time' => 'http://www.***.nl/wp-content/themes/***/uploads/resized_1372667650.jpg',
 'thumbnail' => 'http://www.***.nl/wp-content/themes/***/uploads/resizedThumbnail_1372667650.jpg',
 'line_total' => 83,
 'line_tax' => 0,
 'line_subtotal' => 83,
 'line_subtotal_tax' => 0,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 278 is in (assuming that the `variation_id` property has public visibility):

```
echo $product['data']->variation_id;
```

The use of `print_r()` or `var_dump()` would be more appropriate if you want to see the data structure for debugging. `var_export()` does some additional processing that makes the result parse-able which you don't need to for debugging purposes.

Comment: Weird, I posted this question in a different format earlier, and someone requested var_export there. 
Thanks for your answer, it was what I was looking for.

Comment: @user25312 Maybe it's a personal preference thing, but for me `var_export` adds unnecessary clutter. Also, it doesn't show property visibility like print_r and var_dump do. Take this for example, it just seems clearer to me: http://codepad.org/R5CrbzPi

Answer (score 2):

`$product['data]->variation_id` will give you 278.

Comment: This is incorrect, `WC_Product_Variation` is the class name not variable name.

Comment: in the mean time I noticed myself, got confused with all the structural information